# Usign font-awesome icons as package in vuejs application

Tags: vue.js, font-awesome

I have been trying to use font awesome icons in my vuejs application, I followed the step as given in the link:

```
https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/how-to-use-fon-awesome-5-on-vuejs-project-ff0f28310821
```

However I have css which I reference in CSS font-awesome ICON but it does not seems to be working.

```
th.sortable::after {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f0dc";
  position: absolute;
  left: 29px;
  color: #999;
}
```

this does not shows the icon, if I directly place CDN url into index.html it works.

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

anyone gotta a same problem ?

Thanks

Comment: So which approach you have been trying from tge article? The third one won't work with css `content`, cause it's not a font.

Comment: actually i tried both, with no luck